# access the data from promise all

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, cloudinary

Hi hope you have a nice day
Actually, that's a function after I return multiple images using multer I try that and it works perfectly but now I want to access **result** variable

```
 req.body.images = [];
  const images = [];
  await Promise.all(
    req.files.map(
      catchAsync(async file => {
        let result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path);

      })
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `Promise.all`:

> Creates a Promise that is resolved with an array of results when all of the provided Promises resolve, or rejected when any Promise is rejected.

So you can simply do:

```
req.body.images = [];
const images = [];
const result = await Promise.all(
  req.files.map(
    catchAsync(async (file) => {
      await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path);
    })
  )
);
```